# How to remove Duplicate Content

Tags: html, seo

If am presented with duplicate content on these 
URLS http://www.testman.com/about-us 
and 
http://www.testman.com/about-us/ 
what is the best course of action to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this a test, man? That's the same URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution is

Permanent redirect :

Use the following in Apache .htaccess

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/about-us$ /about-us/
```

the google will index just 1 url

```
/about-us/
```

For multiple urls

you can use :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ([^/]+)$ /$1/
```

Comment: is there any other solution ??? based on SEO ?